# Know a .htaccess mod_rewrite work-around for loading xml files?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Here is my current `.htaccess` code (turn engine on and such):

```
RewriteRule ^foo\.xml$ bar.php [NC]
```

This code works fantastic on domain-names like `foobar.com`, etc. It does not work for temporary domains like such: `bar.com/~foo/`.

Is there a work-around for this?

Answer (score 1):

The **RegEx** you are checking with is evaluating if `foo.xml` *is* the request, but with folders, the request would be more like `~foo/foo.xml`.  Add another rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/foo.xml$ bar.php [NC]
```

I didn't check it yet, but something like that should help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?foo\.xml$ $1bar.php
```